# Execute multiple files from a folder and later to calculate the average using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple .csv files in a folder, where each file contains few columns with some integer values. I want to take one column (e.g. 1st) and later, want to find the sum of that column. At the end, the average of all files, which means 'total sum of all files/number of files'.
I started as following,

```
import os

folder_path = r'folder\path'
total_sum = 0
file_count = 0
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            df=file.readlines()   #not sure
            df.columns=['A', 'B', 'C']
            df1 = df['A'].sum()   #not sure
            total_sum += df1
            file_count += 1
            print(f'Sum for {file_name}: {df1}')

average = total_sum / file_count
print(f'Average of all accuracy: {average}')
```

But, I am unable to read these .csv files, thereby to execute the rest code. A little clue or help will be appreciated.

Comment: To read a .CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame use `df = pd.read_csv(filepath)`. There are other options in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but you just need to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/%5D) to simplify dealing with CSV files. Here's a code snippet to get you started.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = ... # Enter your absolute/relative folder path here
total_sum = 0
file_count = 0

# Loop through all files in the directory
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # NOTE: if some files in the folder are not CSV, can add an error check.
    
    # Read in the file into a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name))
    
    # NOTE: you should add an error check for column_name in the df
    column_name = ... # Enter the column you want to sum over
    file_sum = df[column_name].sum()

    total_sum += file_sum
    file_count += 1

    print(f"Sum for {file_name}: {file_sum}")

if file_count == 0:
    average = 0.
else:
    average = total_sum / file_count
print(f"Average of all accuracy: {average}")
```

Comment: I solved it by replacing 'df=file.readlines()' with 'df = pd.read_csv(filepath)'. Thanks though!